# Undefined return when trying to get html fro ejs.renderFile in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm trying to generate a screenshot from HTML

```
async function makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week) {
    // get meters from meter
    const meter = meters.find(it => it.prm === meterId);
    const weeklyData = await generateWeeklyGraph(meter, week);
    ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/partials/', "weekly_graph.ejs"), {
    }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            return
        }
        console.log(data); // Actually printing good value
        return data
    });
}
```

When I invoke this function:

```
data = await makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week)
console.log("generated WeeklyReport", data) // returns undefined
```

data is `undefined`

but when I do `console.log(data);` in `makeWeeklyReport()`, it actually prints the html.

I thought the `await`  keyword was supposed to wait the end of async function.

I already tried to put:

```
res.render(view, {.., async:true, ... }...)
```

but it is not working

How should I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

`ejs.renderFile` is not an async function/does not return a promise and will call the passed callback-function once it has finished rendering. Since you cannot directly return a value from a callback, rhis won't work.

However, you can wrap the call in a promise and resolve it, once the callback is called (note that I'm `rejecting` the promise in case of an error, you can change this of course and `resolve` the promise in that case as well instead):

```
async function makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week) {
    const meter = meters.find(it => it.prm === meterId);
    const weeklyData = await generateWeeklyGraph(meter, week);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // get meters from meter

        ejs.renderFile(path.join(__dirname, './views/partials/', "weekly_graph.ejs"), {}, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return reject(err);
            }
            console.log(data); // Actually printing good value
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

You can then await this function and process the resolved value:

```
data = await makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week);
```

Comment: I get a conflict with: `await generateWeeklyGraph(meter, week);` as function isn't async anymore

Comment: Oh, I've overlooked this sorry, should be fixed now.

Comment: I still have errors, but I don't know where it comes from. Just let me check it out, and I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `async` / `await`.

Your `return` statements are within a callback function, so nothing is returning in your `makeWeeklyReport` function.

You can use a `Promise` to unwrap the callback values.

```
async function makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week) {
    // get meters from meter
    const meter = meters.find(it => it.prm === meterId);
    const weeklyData = await generateWeeklyGraph(meter, week);

    const [err, data] = await new Promise(resolve => {
        const p = path.join(__dirname, './views/partials/', "weekly_graph.ejs");
        ejs.renderFile(p, { }, (err, data) => resolve([err, data]);
    });

    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log(data); // Actually printing good value
    return data;
}
```

---

To improve readability, you could even wrap `renderFile` as an `async` function:

```
function renderFileAsync(path, data) {
    return new Promise(resolve => ejs.renderFile(path, data,
        (err, data) => resolve([err, data]));
}
```

Then your `makeWeeklyReport` function could be written like this:

```
async function makeWeeklyReport(meterId, week) {
    // get meters from meter
    const meter = meters.find(it => it.prm === meterId);
    const weeklyData = await generateWeeklyGraph(meter, week);

    const p = path.join(__dirname, './views/partials/', "weekly_graph.ejs");
    const [err, data] = await renderFileAsync(p, { });

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    return data;
}
```